# Can't send mail through php in html

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to develope a personal website as a projecet to one of my classes.
I don't understand much of html so i actually can't make my php work.
Please Help.

I've already tried copying and changing php codes from other fonts but nothing works...

**This is the html code:**

```
<div class="container">
   <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="height:100px"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `php` code?

Comment: I didn't copy the code right!!
PLEASE HELP!!

Here is the right code in html:

<div class="container">
            <form action="css/mail.php" method="POST">

                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">

                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">


                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="height:100px"></textarea>

                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>

Comment: I tried copying but it didn't work so i actually have no php code

Comment: The code still not contains no  `php` code, please search for: send email php form

Comment: Already tried copying but it doesn't work because of of the fields i have on my website

Comment: Try to `post` what you have tried till now , also what `exactly` is not working in your code , did you got any error?

Answer (score -2):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="height:100px"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];

      $to_email = $email; // mail whom you want to send
      $subject = ''; // your subject for sending email
      $message = $name.' sent you message. <br><br>'.$message;
      $headers = 'From: noreply@company.com'; // your mail id

      mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers);

      echo "This email is sent using PHP Mail";
   }
?>
```

Use this above code, this will pass the name, email, message to mail function.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for your info. I am beginner. Please support me to make high reputation.